# What expressions for QGIS field-calculator?

Tags: qgis, python, sql, field-calculator

I do not understand what language I have to use in field-calculator and labels on QGIS:

SQL or Python?

And where I can find the possible script/expressions to use?

in the image you can see the options for expressions in QGIS 1.8 italian version

Thanks

[image: Expressions in Italian version]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the field calculator? That will help steer you to appropriate sample scripts.

Comment: How can I find other expression like this one discovered here " CASE WHEN ( "field1" > 0) THEN ( "field2" ) END "?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

QGIS doesn't use SQL or Python (..yet) for it's field calculator.  It uses it's own simple expression language.  It is modeled off a SQL-like style but is not really any SQL dialect in particular.

All the functions can be found in the expression builder itself:

[image]

Comment: Expression like "CASE WHEN () THEN () END"

Comment: In the Conditional group.

Comment: Added the picture with expressions in italian version: I cannot find "conditionals" group. Also english manual v1.8 do not show "conditionals" group

Comment: Ahh its not in the 1.8 tree. It will still in 1.8 I think. Your case expression was right it should work.

Comment: sorry @Nathan W but I do not undestand where to find this option

Comment: Just type `CASE WHEN "somefield" = 'somevalue' THEN 'balh' END` in the expression box.

Comment: I discover this expression here and I start to use it correctly, but I was curious to know other expressions to use

Comment: That is about the only hidden feature in 1.8 expression builder.  Everything is covered correctly in 2.0 UI.

Comment: OK. So I will discover the expressions with the new QGIS 2.0. Thanks