# Automatically insert file path in QGIS table

Tags: qgis

I'm using R to create some plots that refer to specific values of some point in QGIS. Each plot is saved into a directory and for each point in QGIS I added a column with the path to the file.

I know 2 different method to display these plots in QGIS:

- using the Action tool (Open file)
- using the Field tab of the Properties menu of the layer changing the Widget from Modify value to Photo

What if I have to do tons of plots or if I have a large point dataset? Is there a way to add automatically the path to the file in the attribute table? I tried to use the field calculator but I cannot figure out the problem.

Thanks to all

BTW: QGIS 2.1.0 master on Debian 7.3

Comment: What did you try with the field calculator?

Comment: I tried to duplicate the field of the path already written.. obviously without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the syntax of the expressions used in the Field Calculator (   look at [What expressions for QGIS field-calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74084/what-expressions-for-qgis-field-calculator))

In my case, for example, every record of the layer is linked to a html file whose name is based on a numeric field of the table and I need to build the complete path of the file (ie : mypath/folder/4720988.html')

The expression:

New field (url2) =

```
'mypath/folder'               -> 'string variable' (your path, for example)
     ||                       -> concatenate 
         tostring("IDENT")    -> convert each value of the "Field" to string
             ||               -> concatenate
                '.html'       -> 'string variable'
```

[image]

give this result:

[image]

If I want to update the contents of my field with a new path ('myotherpath/othefolder/')

Update field (url2):

```
replace("url2",'mypath/folder','myotherpath/othefolder')
```

Result

[image]

You can even use regular expressions

Comment: Awesome!!!! Thanks! I will spend more time to improve the field calculator possibilities.