# What language is used in QGIS 3 label expressions?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

What language is used in QGIS 3.x's label expressions?

Initially, I thought it's python. But when I tried to concatenate a string and a number field as follows (in `Layer property Labels -> Single Labels`):

```
name + str(id)
```

I got an error about `Function is not known` (I guess [str()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)).

Is the language here python, PostSQL or something else?

Comment: If you use the expression builder to write your label expression, you will find all the functions with their descriptions and syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A similar question was asked a while ago which was answered by one of the main core developers, [@Matthias Kuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn) which you should give a read as it describes the language being close to SQL :)

[What language do QGIS expressions use, what language should QGIS queries be written in?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247474/what-language-do-qgis-expressions-use-what-language-should-qgis-queries-be-writ)

---

But if you want to convert to a string, the equivalent expression would be to use `to_string()`:

```
name + to_string(id)
```