Formatting QGIS expressions
I write quite a few moderately complicated expressions in Qgis and would like to keep them tidy. As I don't have a background writing code the conventions I should be following are a bit of a mystery. One solution that might work is to use a site such as https://formatter.org/cpp-formatter  but I am not sure what style of formatting would be most appropriate for Qgis expressions as to my knowledge they are their own language.

Qgis expression are close to SQL (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247474/what-language-do-qgis-expressions-use-what-language-should-qgis-queries-be-writ), the other language used in QGIS is Python

I tried formatting as SQL using SQL formatter but that puts a space after $s   which is a shame. I should review something like this https://learnsql.com/blog/24-rules-sql-code-formatting-standard/ but it would be nice to have something that automatically tidies a mess of pasted together expression

I often use notepad++ with the SQLinForm plugin for my QGIS expression, it's not perfect (the plugin free version doesn't let you personnalise formatting) but i find it good enough in most case...

@J.R Notepad++ is where I normally deal with large expressions so that plugin is ideal, thanks!

This feels sort of like two separate questions: how to manually format and how to automatically format.
As far as I know, there are no tools available to automatically format QGIS expressions. There might be some tools that are lenient enough to work if the language is similar enough (such as SQL as has been pointed out in the comments), but it is not a guarantee. The most convenient solution would be a button to format the expression right inside QGIS, you might want to open a feature request for that.
As for manually formatting, that is really up to your own sense of "what looks nice and is easy to read". In languages such as QGIS expressions a common option is to add the parameters of a function call on a new line:
do_something(
  "foo",
  3,
  'bar'
)

You may be able to find some inspiration from other "style guides" for various languages, such as the Google C++ style guide. In general, the most important part is to be reasonably consistent.
